# How do I change an inline script tag further down page before it fires

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce, enhanced-ecommerce

I have an ecommerce thank you page that is sending an ecommerce.js hit to Google Analytics

```
<script>
        try{ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
        ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
            'id': '082918-074143-128'
            , 'affiliation': ''
            , 'revenue': '2.09'
            , 'shipping': '0.00'
            , 'tax': '0.17'
        });ga('ecommerce:addItem',{ 
            'id': '082918-074143-128'
            , 'sku': ''
            , 'name': 'Cane Creek 1-1/8-inch Headset Shim Spacer .25mm'
            , 'category': 'Bicycling Catalog > Components > Headsets'
            , 'price': '1.08'
            , 'quantity': '1'
        });

        ga('ecommerce:addItem',{ 
            'id': '082918-074143-128'
            , 'sku': ''
            , 'name': 'Race Face X-Type BB Outer Race Seal Gray'
            , 'category': 'Bicycling Catalog > Components > Other > Other'
            , 'price': '0.84'
            , 'quantity': '1'
        }); ga('ecommerce:send');}catch(err){}
</script>
```

I want to alter this script before it sends the data to GA by removing the first and last lines, as well as changing the code by changing the string `'ga('` to `'ga1('`
so that the code won't send data to GA. and so that I can instead send the enhanced ecommerce hit instead.

I have inserted the following script higher on the page so that it would edit the tag lower on the page, but it fails to edit the tag before it fires.

I tried this:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    function contains(selector, text) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        return [].filter.call(elements, function(element){
            return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
        });
    }
    function bsHit() {
        gaHit = contains('script', /try\{ga\(/g);
        var hit = gaHit[0].innerHTML;
        var tryer = "try{ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js')\;";
        var hit = hit.replace(tryer, "");
        lastLine = "ga('ecommerce:send');}catch(err){}";
        hit = hit.replace(lastLine, "");
        hit = hit.replace(/ga\(/g,"ga1\(");
        console.log(hit);
    }

    bsHit();
  }
</script>
```

What do I need to / modify in my code to make it happen?

I appreciate your time and insights.

Comment: Why are you trying to rewrite the first block with script, instead of just editing it?

Comment: if by "edit", you mean on the server, the first script is autogenerated by the ecommerce platform and I can't manually change it. I WISH I could!

Comment: Ok, well the DOMContentLoaded event does not happen before any scripts execute (see https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded), so that won't work. You could try wrapping your code in an immediately-invoked function expression instead of the event listener. Also, I don't see why you need all three replace statements. Replacing "ga('ecommerce:send')" with "" will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. I don't fully understand what your 'contains' function is doing, so I can't vouch for that. In any case, if you use the GA debugger chrome extension, you should be able to see if your code executes before the autogenerated code, and troubleshoot from there.

```js
<script>
(function() { //this wraps your sript in an IIFE, which will execute as soon as it's parsed

 function contains(selector, text) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return [].filter.call(elements, function(element) {
   return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
  });
 }

 function bsHit() {
  var gaHit = contains('script', /try\{ga\(/g);
  var hit = gaHit[0].innerHTML;
  hit = hit.replace("ga('ecommerce:send')", "");
  gaHit[0].innerHTML = hit; //var hit is just a string - you need to rewrite the script element
  console.log("Replaced script content:\n" + hit); //added string so it will show up on console even if 'hit' is null
 }

 bsHit();
})();
</script>
```

Comment: If I place your  code block above the ecommerce.js hit, it still executes the ecommerce hit before it gets modified.

Comment: Oh well. Thinking about it, I don't see how this is possible. As a script is loaded, it is executed, so you can't edit it in the DOM before it is executed. Can't you just enable enhanced ecommerce in the view, then add your own tag? The legacy ecommerce reporting is gone when you do that, isn't it? If that doesn't work, some version of DenverMatt's idea seems like your best option, though that won't work either if you can't modify the script before it executes.

Comment: If I place your code block above the ecommerce.js hit, the first script can't find the can't find the script (I assume because it hasn't loaded in the dom yet) and chrome returns the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined.`  

Here's a [test page](https://bikeshopseo.com/assets/files/test3.html) to show the error.

Comment: I enabled enhanced ecommerce and I'm getting enhanced ecommerce data except the detail to buy data.  That is coming through blank.  My ecommerce hit is sending the correct data, but I thought that the problem is that there is both an ecommerce.js hit and and ec.js on same page. which google says to avoid [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce)

And that was why I was trying to disable the ecommerce.js hit.

Comment: Not sure about having both on the same page. In any case, my solution won't work per my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just stub the ga function with something else temporarily?

```js
window.ga1 = window.ga;
window.ga = function(){};
setTimeout(function(){ window.ga = window.ga1; }, 3000);
```

Comment: Using equals here assigns ga1 to the same object as ga, which means that the value of ga1 will change when you change ga. You would need to clone ga for this to work. Also, this may prevent pageview or event tracking from working.